# Use sort order from TCA select to list items in fluid

Tags: sorting, typo3, fluid, extbase

In my **TCA** I use a `select` to an other table.

```
    'modules' => [
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myextension_module_table/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myextension_domain_model_semester.modules',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'enableMultiSelectFilterTextfield' => true,
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_myextension_domain_model_module',
            'minitems' => 1,
            'maxitems' => 99,
        ],
    ],
```

Under "Selected Items" I can sort the items. Now I want to use this sort order in fluid. In database I see the right order `21,1,2,3,4,28`. But in fluid the items are always sorted by uid.

Adding `'sortby' => 'sorting',` with all needed changes doesn't solve my problem. In this case I can order records in list view. But I don't want this order. I want to show order from "Selected Items" in frontend.

In my **ModuletableController.php** I get the selected moduletable from Flexform.

```
/**
 * action show
 *
 * @param \Vendor\Myextension\Domain\Model\Moduletable $moduletable
 * @return void
 */
public function showAction(\Vendor\Myextension\Domain\Model\Moduletable $moduletable = NULL) {
    if (is_null($moduletable)) {
        $moduletable = $this->moduletableRepository->findByUid($this->settings['singleModuleTable']);
    }

    $this->view->assign('moduletable', $moduletable);
}
```

An in the **template** Show.html I loop through it.

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers">
<f:layout name="Default" />

<f:section name="main">
    <h2>{moduletable.title}</h2>
    <f:for each="{moduletable.semester}" as="semester">
        <p>{semester.title}</p>
        <f:for each="{semester.modules}" as="module">
            <p{module.title}</p>
        </f:for>
    </f:for>
</f:section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to use MM tables. Then sort order is set in TCA select field.

In TCA:

```
'modules' => [
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myextension_domain_model_semester.modules',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
        'enableMultiSelectFilterTextfield' => true,
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_myextension_domain_model_module',
        'foreign_sortby' => 'sorting',
        'MM' => 'tx_myextension_semester_module_mm',
        'minitems' => 1,
        'maxitems' => 99,
    ],
],
```

In ext_tables.sql

```
CREATE TABLE tx_myextension_semester_module_mm (
    uid_local int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    uid_foreign int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    sorting int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    sorting_foreign int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

    KEY uid_local (uid_local),
    KEY uid_foreign (uid_foreign)
);
```

Comment: Thanks that works great. You can use the SQL command 1:1 like this and it works directly. (Attention: Don't forget to execute in the backend on Analyze Database Structure in Maintenance).
Warning: All previous links to this field will be gone. You have to set them again.

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the selected items in your Extbase controller? Maybe you can use this findByUidListOrderByList function here: http://blog.teamgeist-medien.de/2014/09/typo3-extbase-repository-find-by-multiple-uids-findbyuids.html#comment-90

Comment: I extend my question. In my controller I get only the parent -parent object and then iterate trough them.

Comment: I know this and unfortunately it seems to be the only way. Is there a straight way to get the comma separated list of references objects? I always get the objects ordered by IDs.